# Redirect to another page in reactJS onClick

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a reactJS web App , im stuck in this problem . I want to use  or any other method to redirect to another page after testing a value from the server.
I tried this :

```
      <Link to='/Upload'>
          <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={async () => {
            await verificationp(phone, code).then(async (result) => {
              if ((await result) === true) {
                //I want to redirect to another page
              } else {
                //I want to display an alert
              }
            });
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
    </Link>
```

Comment: are you using react-router-dom?

Comment: If you're using `react-router-dom` have you tried the `<Redirect />` tag. You can use it like this : `<Redirect from="/current/location" to="/next/location" />`

Comment: i already used the redirect tag but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the Link component in this example.  Try using the history prop (**props.history.push('/')**) See the below examples, the last one should apply to you:

In your App.js router:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
  <Route path="/errorpage" component={ErrorPage} />
  <Route path="/" exact component={HomeScreen} />
  <Redirect to='/' />
</Switch>
```

On the page where you want to redirect:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Auth = props => {

    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        data: {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    })

    const authHandler = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        try {
            // await dispatch(action) // dispatch to redux or send a fetch
            props.history.push('/')  // redirects if no errors
        } catch (err) {
            props.history.push('/errorpage')  // redirects if an error
        }
    }

    const inputChangedHandler = e => {
        setForm({
            ...form,
            data: {
                ...form.data,
                [e.target.id]: e.target.value
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={authHandler}>
                <input id='email' type='email' value={form.data.email} onChange={inputChangedHandler} />
                <input id='password' type='password' value={form.data.password} onChange={inputChangedHandler} />
                <button type='submit'>Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Auth
```

In your case try the below if the page is on the route stack the history prop will be available or you will have to use withRouter or useHistory hook to get access to the history prop.

```
const clickHandler = () => {
     try {
         // await dispatch(action)
         props.history.push('/')  // redirects
     } catch (err) {
         props.history.push('/errorpage')  // redirects
     }
}

return (<button type='button' onClick={clickHandler}>Click Me</button)
```

Comment: I didin't understand your last example

Comment: In my Auth component example above:  When you load a Route that is between the Switch statement (like the Auth component above) is forwards a history prop with it.  You can use that history prop in functions to move between pages.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [Redirect doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

I think best thing you can do is create a separate function for onClick and change a state to redirect, so this way you can prevent some action by user while request is in progress

```
const [redirectTo, setRedirectTo] = useState('');

const chekcfromServer = async () => {
  await verificationp(phone, code).then(async (result) => {
    if ((await result) === true) {
      setRedirectTo('/somewhereinyour/application')
    } else {
      // I want to display an alert
    }
  });
};
```

and when in render

```
return (
    <>
        redirectTo && <Redirect to={{pathname: redirectTo }} />
       ...rest of your code
    </>
)
```

Comment: I tried the first solution , i get this error :  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: @louaybaccary second one? I have removed the first one

Answer (score 0):

You can use "redirect" from "react-router-dom"

Example:

```
    import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

    <Link to='/Upload'>
          <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={async () => {
            await verificationp(phone, code).then(async (result) => {
              if ((await result) === true) {
                //I want to redirect to another page

                return <Redirect to="your_url" />

              } else {
                //I want to display an alert
              }
            });
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
    </Link>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but when i click on the button nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the state system (Redux) to resolve this issue.

So my problem was I wanted to fire an *event.preventDefault()* to stop a link being clicked, but then I wanted to do an API call after it (to check login status, as it was a complex IoT device) and click the link if the check was fine, but not click the link if it wasn't. *However*, the *event.PreventDefault()* stopped me doing this, because it cancels any events (I'm sure there are nicer ways to achieve this! but time targets and all that).

I solved this by:

1. Having my usual async function with the *event.preventDefault()* inside it.
2. Within the first call I set some state in Redux, just a basic boolean.
3. If the API check was successful then I call the same click function again (using *.click()*) and bypass the *event.preventDefault()* thanks to Redux (then reset the state afterwards) which forces the re-direct. If the check failed then I display an error message and don't display again (while obviously updating Redux).

The State Management system inside React is very powerful. You can do some hacky things! but sometimes the other *"correct"* solutions don't work for you; for example the history props functionality, which you can get round that other ways via State Management.